# What is the vectorized code for the following code snippet for octave

Tags: machine-learning, vectorization, octave

Can anyone help me with conversion of the following code to vectorized form ??

```
z=X*theta;
g=sigmoid(z);
for i=1:m
  J=J+((-y(i)*log(g(i)))-((1-y(i))*log(1-g(i))));
end
```

I have tried the following

```
z=X*theta;
g=sigmoid(z);
J=J+((-y).*log(g)-((1-y).*log(1-g)));
```

but this prints a particular value m times. and also wrong answer.

the answer for J is 0.693 which i get right using for loop but for the vectorized implementation i get 0.00693.

What's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `y`, `X` and `theta`?

Comment: Y is m*1 vector , X is m*3 matrix and theta is 3*1 vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking J, and adding all the `-y(i)*log(g(i))-(1-y(i))*log(1-g(i))` to it.

So you need to take `J` and add (`sum`) all those things.

```
J=J+sum(  (-y).*log(g)-(1-y).*log(1-g)  );
```